# Flutter web next page name shows in url but current page frozen and no longer responding to gestures

Tags: flutter, flutter-web-browser

Just developed a simple flutter web app and seems to be working fine. Only problem am facing is: On say PageB I have a bunch of TextFormFields all having autoFocus set to false. Pressing a button should take user to PageC which has another TextFormField with autoFocus false as well. However when the button on PageB is pressed, the page/screen just seem to freeze. On the address bar, I can see it showing PageC url but PageB is still frozen. I am using context.pushNamed (GoRouter) for navigation but can't still access PageC. Behaviour is just happening on moving from PageB to PageC. I was able to move from PageA to PageB without any issue. Also issue only occurring on running the web app on a mobile browsers. I have been on this more than a day, any help?

Comment: I'm sure you're aware of this as a 1.6K rep user.. but it's hard to answer this question in its current state. Providing a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and other points mentioned in [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help others help, and in the process of making an MRE you often answer the question yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging this, I realised there was a widget in PageC the was having a render errors and hence freezes the screen but because it was freezing at the initial build method, it wasn't appearing on screen and hence was stuck at PageB.